# How do i use partial specialization on two parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I could swear the syntax is correct. I played around and changed `class` into `typename`. Still no go.

How do i write this so the 2nd function template kicks in?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename TT> void fn(T t, TT tt) { std::cout<<"general"<<std::endl; }
template<> void fn<T, bool>(T t, bool tt) { std::cout<<"bool"<<std::endl; }
int main(){
    fn("", "");
    fn("", true);
}
```

Comment: On specializations of function templates also see [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no partial specializations of function templates. Just use overloading instead:

```
template<typename T> void fn(T t, bool tt) { std::cout<<"bool"<<std::endl; }
```